# Weird behavior with max function

Tags: c++, max

I have this code:

```
largestDeviation = max(max(max(angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtA),
                               angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtB)),
                           angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtC)),
                       angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtD)),
                       angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtE);
```

The method: `angleBetweenVectors` returns a `float`.

I can't see what this code is doing and why it's actually building, the brackets aren't matching up properly and Im afraid its going to cause errors. How can I just get the maximum value of all of my calls to `angleBetweenVectors`?

Comment: I would simplify it by making a `std::vector<float>`, using `push_back()` to add your floats to the vector, then call `std::max` to find the largest. It might not be super fast, but it would be readable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add some indetation and you get:

```
largestDeviation = 
max(
   max(
      max(
         angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtA),
         angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtB)
      ),
      angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtC)
   ),
   angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtD)
), 
angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtE);
```

I.e. It will return the value for `angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtE);` as you are missing a `max`

Answer (score 3):

You can use standard algorithm std::max that has as a parameter  `std::initializer_list`
For example

```
#include <algorithm>
//...

largestDeviation = std::max(
{
   angleBetweenVectors( robustNormal, normalAtA ), 
   angleBetweenVectors( robustNormal, normalAtB ),
   angleBetweenVectors( robustNormal, normalAtC ), 
   angleBetweenVectors( robustNormal, normalAtD ), 
   angleBetweenVectors( robustNormal, normalAtE )
} );
```

As for you code then it determine the maximum value among values returned by corresponding calls of function angleBetweenVectors. The code uses standard algorithm `std::max` that has two parameters and determinates the maximum between two arguments.

For example the inner call

```
max( angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtA ),
     angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtB ) ),
```

finds the maximum between two values returned by the function calls. The result of the function `std::max` along with the next call if the function in turn is used in the enclosing `std::max` call.

By the way your code has a compilation error There should be one more call of `std::max`

```
largestDeviation = 

max(
   max(
      max(
         max( angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtA ),
              angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtB) 
         ),
         angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtC)
      ),
      angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtD) 
   ),
   angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtE)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write your code also like this:

```
maxAngle = angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtA);
maxAngle = max(angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtB), maxAngle);
maxAngle = max(angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtC), maxAngle);
maxAngle = max(angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtD), maxAngle);
maxAngle = max(angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtE), maxAngle);
```

Or, more aligned, when choosing a good initial value for `maxAngle`, e.g. I would say `-2*M_PI`:

```
maxAngle = -2 * M_PI;
maxAngle = max(angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtA), maxAngle);
maxAngle = max(angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtB), maxAngle);
maxAngle = max(angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtC), maxAngle);
maxAngle = max(angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtD), maxAngle);
maxAngle = max(angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtE), maxAngle);
```

Comment: That's not answering the question.

Comment: Yes, is not answering, but I hope that this is helping. The complete answer is given by @Ed Heal.

Answer (score 1):

**C++11**

```
#include <algorithm>

largestDeviation = std::max({
   angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtA),
   angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtB),
   angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtC),
   angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtD),
   angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, normalAtE)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// Store all your normals in a vector
std::vector<normal> normals;
normals.push_back(normalAtA);
normals.push_back(normalAtB);
normals.push_back(normalAtC);
normals.push_back(normalAtD);
normals.push_back(normalAtE);

// Iterate through your vector, and check each angle to see if it is the new max
max_val = 0;
vector<normal>::iterator it;
for (it = normals.begin(); it != normals.end(); ++it)
{
    max_val = max(max_val, angleBetweenVectors(robustNormal, *it));
}
```

Comment: Seems a bit of overkill

Comment: @EdHeal Yes for this simple case it probably is. I was just trying to think of something more general in case they have many more normals to compare.